# If condition is not working if the alert box code is not included in the loop - only on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

The `if` condition loop is not working on IOS devices. However if I add the `alertbox` code it works. Kindly help me to fix it. Please check the code `if (iScrollPos == 0)`

I tried with `return false`, `setTimeout()`, still it was not working. On scroll up when I reach the scroll position equal to zero, I'm adding and removing the classes.

```js
// Code starts Here for Global menu on scroll down hide navbar on scroll up show navbar
var iScrollPos = 0;
//$(document.body).on('touchmove', onScroll); // for mobile
//$(window).on('scroll', onScroll); 
document.addEventListener("touchmove", ScrollStart, false);
document.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll, false);

function detectDirection() {
  var iCurScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  //console.log("iCurScrollPos"+iCurScrollPos);
  if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
    //Scrolling Down
    direction = "down";
  } else {
    //Scrolling Up
    direction = "up";
  }
  iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;
  return direction;
}

function headerSlide() {
  var cookieHeight = $(".cookie-cont").height();
  var headerHeight = 85;
  if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    detectDirection();
    if (direction == "up") {
      //console.log("You Scrolled Up");
      $("#toggle-section .header").addClass('position-fixed');
      $("#toggle-section .header").removeClass('position-relative');
      $("#toggle-section .header").removeClass('trans-effect');
      $("#toggle-section .header").show();
      if (iScrollPos == 0) {
        $("#toggle-section .header").removeClass('position-fixed');
        $("#toggle-section .header").addClass('position-relative');
        alertbox("Scroll positions reaches top of the screen remove the fixed header");
      } else if (($("#toggle-section .header").hasClass('position-fixed')) && ($(".find-a-dealer").hasClass('scrolled'))) {
        $(".scrolled").css({
          'top': cookieHeight + 85 + 'px'
        });
      }
    } else if (iScrollPos > 400) {
      //console.log("You Scrolled Down");
      $("#toggle-section .header").removeClass('position-fixed');
      $("#toggle-section .header").addClass('position-relative');
      $("#toggle-section .header").addClass('trans-effect');
      $("#toggle-section .header").hide();
      if (($("#toggle-section .header").hasClass('position-fixed')) && ($(".find-a-dealer").hasClass('scrolled'))) {
        $(".scrolled").css({
          'top': cookieHeight + 85 + 'px'
        });
      }
      if (($("#toggle-section .header").hasClass('position-relative')) && ($(".find-a-dealer").hasClass('scrolled'))) {
        $(".scrolled").css({
          'top': cookieHeight + 'px '
        });
      }
    } else if ((iScrollPos < 400) && ($("#toggle-section .header").hasClass('position-fixed')) && ($(".find-a-dealer").hasClass('scrolled'))) {
      $(".scrolled").css({
        'top': cookieHeight + 85 + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      $("#toggle-section .header").addClass('position-fixed');
      $("#toggle-section .header").removeClass('position-relative');
      $("#toggle-section .header").removeClass('trans-effect');
      $("#toggle-section .header").show();
    }
  }
}

function ScrollStart() {
  //Start of scroll event for iOS
  headerSlide()
}

function Scroll() {
  //End of scroll event for iOS
  //start/end of scroll event for other browsers
  headerSlide()
}
```